# Is taking hostages permitted in Islam?

Tags: sharia, war

Is taking hostages, especially of non-combatants such as Kenji Goto, permitted in Islam? I'm especially interested in the Sunni or Salafi viewpoint.

Comment: I doubt there is a specific discussion on taking hostages. That might fall under the broader category of oppressing someone, or enslaving a free person (both of which are major sins). Are you asking in the context of war? Are prisoners of war considered hostages?

Comment: @Ansari I don't think Goto would count as a prisoner of war, as he was not a combatant.

Comment: Goto went there to rescue his friend Haruna Yukawa. Not sure how he planned to rescue. Haruna Yukawa went there as a military contractor.

Comment: @Ziyad Goto wouldn't use violence to rescue Yukawa! He's a peaceful man. https://twitter.com/mademaiselle/status/559155632800923648

Comment: He went there as journalist but intention was rescuing Yakawa. Even if he did not have intention to fight, he can do harm to ISIS by spying them, like finding where his friend is and sending his location. This can result in Japan or allies trying to directly rescue the hostages.

Comment: @Ziyad I suggest you read about Kenji Goto, and to a lesser extent about the military history of Japan since 1945, and re-consider how likely such a scenario is.

Comment: Do we really need to listen to people who defend murderers?

Comment: @AndrewGrimm, I really approve these kinds of questions as you ask which can be so constructive for the readers... / God Bless You.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an response from a historical perspective.

For starters, it's not considered academically judicious to explain religious concepts using contemporary political movements. Go to the scriptural texts for your authentic answer. The older it is, the closer you will be to the source.

Having said that, during the first battle of Islam - known as the Battle of Badr which the Muslims won - prisoners of war from the pagan Arabs were taken by the Muslims.

These captives, many of whom had persecuted the Muslims for leaving their religion by the use of torture, abduction and murder, were instead treated in a humane and compassionate manner - much to their own surprise.

It is documented that the Muslims fed the pagan captives with baked bread - a luxury in those times - and sustained themselves with dates, which was the staple food.

However a condition was stipulated on the prisoners of war, many of whom were wealthy and therefore educated. "Teach ten Muslims to read and write, and you will be set free." A number of the pagan captives jumped at the opportunity and consequently the Muslims kept their word and emancipated them.

Using the above narrative, it MAY BE inferred that hostages are allowed in Shari'ah, but they were not tortured or beheaded (even though they had tortured and killed many Muslims beforehand), but were instead afforded the kindest treatment and the best food available at the time.

The above conditions of compassion and mercy have to be upheld even in this day and age by the Muslims if they choose to retain hostages or prisoners of war.